# Idiomatic way of saying "stick with crazy glue"

Tags: idiomatic-language

I am not sure if there's a better way of saying this, but "stick something onto something with crazy glue" neither does "stick something with crazy glue" or any variants thereof. Is there any better alternative?

For example:

> He stuck a hat with crazy glue onto his head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People do, informally, use *crazy glue* as a verb.

> He **crazy glued** a hat onto his head.

This is easy, as *glue* is a verb as well as a noun anyway. It's just putting the full product name instead of just *glue*.